# Wep API with Inputs both Form Object and Route Values...Is it good approach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api

I have an Web API, which will receive inputs from the "Route URL" and from the "Request body".

Example:

```
http://mysite/api/GetIds/85/5

    {
       "ids":["1234","1234","1234","1234","1234","1234","1234","1234","1234","1234","1234","1234","1234","1234","1234","1234","1234","1234","1234"]        
    }
```

So Is this better approach?? I know that I can put the route vales in the request object ...but that object is common object. So I dont want to change it. Anyway I just want to know is it the correct way or not??

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [`HTTP`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) method using `get` verb, does not support the `Request Body`, so you cannot pass it in the body of your request. You have to use the Request Header, so, in this case, parameters could be in the `url` which is the get method give to you.

You can use the a `post` request, and pass it on the request body. `Post` and `Put` support request body. To pass a jSon object, you have to apply on the request header the following instruction:

```
content-type: application/json
```

to web-api understand the content you are sending on the `body` is in `json` format and know how to deserialize it for you. You also can use parameters on the url in a post request, since you specify the [`FromUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.fromuriattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and [`FromBody`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.frombodyattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) respectively.

In your method, you could have:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri] int id, [FromBody] string[] ids)
{
   // some process here
   var model = /* create a model to output on the response body, if you need */
   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, model);
}
```

If you have more than a single property in body, could be a good approach using a [`DTO`](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) object, and recieve a instance of this object as a parameter of the `Post` method.

Comment: Very clean explanation..My doubt is passing parameter in the URL and at the same time through the request object is good practice or not. As per your explanation it seems it is valid approach. Thanks you very much...